# Where is my Enlightened badge?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, badges

On [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/80870/25368) someone recently gave me an up vote (yay!) which puts me currently at 10 upvotes. This awarded me the "Nice answer" badge.

[Nice Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/23/nice-answer):

> Answer score of 10 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

[Enlightened](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/19/enlightened):

> First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Now on this question I was the first (only) to answer, and it is the accepted answer, and it has at least 10 votes. What hidden requirement am I missing for the Enlightened badge?

Comment: How long ago were the requirements fulfilled? Badges are only awarded periodically.

Comment: @murgatroid99 only 22 minutes, that's what I thought at first too, yet I received the Nice Answer badge, so I don't think that is it. Unless the Bronze/Silver/Gold badges are awarded on different time intervals?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the interval depends on how common they expect the badge to be. So Enlightened is probably just awarded less often

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all badges are awarded immediately.

For some badges, there is a cron job that checks every so often to see if that badge should be awarded. The cron jobs for less common badges run less frequently.

For more information see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112873/134175

Comment: Oh that does make sense to update dependant on rarity. And thanks for the link too! I'll just twiddle my fingers for now. :)

Comment: The advice I've seen other people give is to only start worrying if it's been a day and you still don't have the badge

Comment: About 1 hour after getting that 10th upvote I got it, thanks!

Comment: glad I could help